# Creating a single timestamp from separate DAY OF YEAR, Year and Time columns in R

Tags: r, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

I have a time series dataset for several meteorological variables. The time data is logged in three separate columns:

1. Year (e.g. 2012)
2. Day of year (e.g. 261 representing 17-September in a Leap Year)
3. Hrs:Mins (e.g. 1610)

Is there a way I can merge the three columns to create a single timestamp in R? I'm not very familiar with how R deals with the Day of Year variable.

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `timeDate` package can handle gregorian time frames.  I haven't used it personally but it looks straightforward. There is a `shift` argument in some methods that allow you to set the offset from your data.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/timeDate.pdf

Because you mentioned it, I thought I'd show the actual code to merge together separate columns. When you have the values you need in separate columns you can use `paste` to bring them together and `lubridate::mdy` to parse them.

```
library(lubridate)

col.month <- "Jan"
col.year <- "2012"
col.day <- "23"

date <- mdy(paste(col.month, col.day, col.year, sep = "-"))
```

Lubridate is a great package, here's the official page: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate

And here is a nice set of examples: http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/03/do-more-with-dates-and-times-in-r-with-lubridate-1-1-0/

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Lubridate is a great package indeed, very helpful to R beginners like myself.

Comment: No problem.  Be sure to check out the other two must have packages by Hadley Wickham and his crew (Winston and Garret).  Their packages make R easier to use and much more consistant.  Plyr and ggplot2: http://blog.rstudio.org/2012/08/20/welcome-hadley-winston-and-garrett/

Comment: Update to my comment: plyr has been replaced by the faster and more consistent dplyr.  dplyr focuses on data frames to work with your data and has pieces of the core written in RCPP for speed.

http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/

Answer (score 3):

You should get quite far using `ISOdatetime`. This function takes vectors of `year`, `day`, `hour`, and `minute` as input and outputs an `POSIXct` object which represents time. You just have to split the third column into two separate `hour` `minute` columns and you can use the function.